# Mysqli num rows and mysqli fetch array issue

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I try to google it but, i really dont understand what is the problem with this query. Here is code

```
include_once("includes/db_connection.php");
//Upit za prikaz pitanja!
$listaPitanja = "";
$sql = "SELECT id, username, question FROM useroptions ORDER BY DESC";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
$pitanjaCount = mysqli_num_rows($user_query); //line 8
if ($pitanjaCount > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))  { //line 10
$id = $row['id'];
$question = $row['question'];
$username = $row['username'];
$listaPitanja .= '<div id="brojOdgovora">'.$id.'</div>
            <div id="tekstPitanja"><h3>'.$question.'</h3></div>
            <div id="userPitanja"><h6>'.$username.'</h6></div>';
    } 
} else {
$listaPitanja = "There is no inserted questions!";
}
```

This query gives me nothing. Just this error  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in something on line 8, and if i delete `ORDER BY DESC` there is some error on line 10?
Sorry if it repeated, but i have no idea to solve this!! Thank you!

Comment: Try the solution from Maarten van Middelaar.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement has no ORDER column:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, question FROM useroptions ORDER BY DESC";
```

Change it with the correct column name:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, question FROM useroptions ORDER BY column_name DESC";
```

Probably, `mysqli_query` is returning `false` instead of `mysqli_result` object.

Answer (score 1):

To add segarci,

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)
```

should be

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)
```